# Merging rows to map type based on max value in a column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a small POC to ingest the user events(CSV file) from a website. Below is the sample input:

[image]

Input Schema:

[image]

Output should be in the format as below

[image]

The logic required is to group by the id column and merge the
name and value columns to a Map type where the name column represents the key
and the value column represent the value in the Map type. The value to be picked for each key in the Map is the one with the highest value in the timestamp column.

I was able to achieve some part where it needs to be grouped by id and extract maximum of the timestamp column.**I am facing difficulty with selecting one value(from corresponding max timestamp) for each id) and merge with other names(using map)**.

Below is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val schema = StructType(List(
    StructField("id", LongType, nullable = true),
    StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("value", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType, nullable = true)))
val myDF = spark.read.schema(schema).option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("wasbs:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/tru.csv")
val df = myDF.toDF("id","name","value","timestamp")
//df.groupBy("id","name","value").agg(max("timestamp")).show()
val windowSpecAgg  = Window.partitionBy("id")
df.withColumn("max", max(col("timestamp")).over(windowSpecAgg)).where(col("timestamp") === col("max")).drop("max").show()
```

Comment: Please don't add sample data as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **window** function and `filter` out latest data by partitioning on `"id","name"`

later use **`map_from_arrays,to_json`** functions to recreate the desired json.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()

//sample data
//+---+----+-------+---------+
//| id|name|  value|timestamp|
//+---+----+-------+---------+
//|  1|   A| Exited|     3201|
//|  1|   A|Running|     5648|
//|  1|   C| Exited|     3547|
//|  2|   C|Success|     3612|
//+---+----+-------+---------+

val windowSpecAgg  = Window.partitionBy("id","name").orderBy(desc("timestamp"))

df.withColumn("max", row_number().over(windowSpecAgg)).filter(col("max")===1).
drop("max").
groupBy("id").
agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("name")),collect_list(col("value")))).as("settings")).
show(10,false)

//+---+----------------------------+
//|id |settings                    |
//+---+----------------------------+
//|1  |{"A":"Running","C":"Exited"}|
//|2  |{"C":"Success"}             |
//+---+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ranking function - `row_number()` to get the latest records per partition.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1, "A", "Exited", 1546333201),
  (3, "B", "Failed", 1546334201),
  (2, "C", "Success", 1546333612),
  (3, "B", "Hold", 1546333444),
  (1, "A", "Running", 1546335648),
  (1, "C", "Exited", 1546333547)).toDF("id", "name", "value", "timestamp")

df.withColumn("rn",
  row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id", "name").orderBy('timestamp.desc_nulls_last)))
  .where('rn === 1)
  .drop("rn")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list(map('name, 'value)).as("settings"))
  .show(false)
/*
+---+-------------------------------+
|id |settings                       |
+---+-------------------------------+
|1  |[[A -> Running], [C -> Exited]]|
|3  |[[B -> Failed]]                |
|2  |[[C -> Success]]               |
+---+-------------------------------+ */
```